# Add languages at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, multilingual

I have a multi-language windows application that uses standard .net localization in resx files.

Now I have a request to add a possibility for user to create his own language files that are not originally supported and add them to the application without recompiling it.

What's the best approach to achieve this?

I'm considering moving the languages to database and then crating a second tool that'll add translations to the database, but would rather keep the current approach, if it's possible to add resx files dynamically.

Comment: This is exactly why I don’t use .NET localization but wrote my own. I store the translations in files separate from the EXE, have a Windows-Forms-based GUI for translation that I can embed in any application (and working on a WPF clone of it), and allow users to switch languages without restarting the application. I don’t get why anyone would want it any different and why Microsoft created such a bad and limited system.

Comment: There are various options to replace the .Net localizer with something easier. Every windows control has a name and you implement a simple name based lookup on form load/language switch.

Comment: @Timwi Thanks for the comment. I decided to go with your approach.Could you write an answer to this question so I can accept it?

Comment: @FedorHajdu: I could, but I’m surprised you find it helpful. I would feel more helpful if I could publish my system and just link you to it, so you wouldn’t have to re-implement it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why I don’t use .NET localization but wrote my own.

I store the translations in files separate from the EXE, have a Windows-Forms-based GUI for translation that I can embed in any application (and working on a WPF clone of it), and allow users to switch languages without restarting the application.

I don’t get why anyone would want it any different and why Microsoft created such a bad and limited system.

Unfortunately, I cannot publish my system right now, but I’m hoping I’ll be able to soon.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can use is keep the translations in an XML file. This way, the user can just drop his own XML file into the folder where the translation exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the translations to .resx file and just add the location of that file to the database and then when you want to translate some label just go to the database to see where that file is and then read from it. I'm not sure though how it would fit with a localisation lib...